# How Paypal works with buying goods/service from my website

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm new to Paypal, IPNs etc. Could someone explain to me the step by step process on how can I track the goods/services purchased from my website up to the process on when do I update my database about the transaction happened.

So far what I know is I get a `payer_id` in the IPN post back when a user finished buying the goods/services from my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paypal documentation is pretty good for this. The process begins with the triggering of your script from the IPN postback. The first thing that script needs to do is verify if the IPN is legitimate. This involves checking that the TXN_ID hasn't been seen before as well as a number of other things and then you send a request to the paypal service to verify that the request was indeed authentic. [This is all covered here.](https://www.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside)

From there what your script does is specific to your application. Does it modify the inventory database? Probably. Does it send an email to the customer? Maybe. Should it access the order information from paypal and write it to a Customer Orders database? Probably. You should check out [using the Paypal APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/) to interface with your account and retrieve information or carry out actions.

[This is a great resource about implementing paypal IPN with PHP.](http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html) I wish I'd had it when I was coding my paypal integration stuff.

And the [Paypal IPN Manual](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/ipnguide.pdf) is invaluable for this.

Comment: how do I attach tracking id when user purchased any products/services ?.so when the status is Completed or Verified. I will update the database using the tracking id and verify in my system that this user_x purchased service/product foo   from my website.

Comment: You can use a hidden input field on the page with your paypal payment button to pass information to the IPN script. See this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736674/paypal-button-ipn-pass-payer-username

Answer (score 2):

A picture is worth a thousand words, So check out picture below to get the idea about how it works. By the way if you google you can find more details.

[image]

[image]